# Error with librosa library

Tags: python, caching, import

So i was working with librosa library in IPython and didn't encounter with any problem so far until yesterday that failed to import it. Specifically when i try to import librosa it gives me the following error message.

```
import librosa

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6ce83e78f094> in <module>()
----> 1 import librosa

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\librosa\__init__.py in <module>()
     12
     13 # And all the librosa sub-modules
---> 14 from . import cache
     15 from . import core
     16 from . import beat

ImportError: cannot import name cache
```

Can somebody inform me what is this message about and how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to fix it ? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I faced a similar problem recently. Are you sure you aren't getting any error before this? Whenever I imported LibRosa, the initial error was 'DLL failed to load' in some scipy module. If I ignored the error and imported LibRosa again, then I'd get  ImportError:cannot import name cache.

So I uninstalled NumPy and SciPy, downloaded them from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and reinstalled them. That fixed all import issues.